# jQuery - Click event on <tr> elements with in a table and getting <td> element values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML in a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) file:

```
<div class="custList">
   <table class="dataGrid">
      <c:forEach var="cust" items="${custList}">
         <tr>
            <td>${cust.number}</td>
            <td>${cust.description}</td>
            <td>${cust.type}</td>
            <td>${cust.status}</td>
        </tr>
     </c:forEach>
  </table>
</div>
```

I need to be able to trigger a `'click'` event on each of the dynamically created `<tr>` tags and also be able to access the values of the `<td>` tags (of the clicked `<tr>`) from within the JavaScript function. I have this function already, but sadly it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.custList > table > tr").live('click', function() {
        alert("You clicked my <tr>!");
        //get <td> element values here!!??
    });
});
```

---

**Update (Jan 2016)**: jQuery.live is deprecated (as noted here:http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unless otherwise definied (`<tfoot>`, `<thead>`), browsers put `<tr>` *implicitly* in a `<tbody>`.

You need to put a `> tbody` in between `> table` and `> tr`:

```
$("div.custList > table > tbody > tr")
```

Alternatively, you can also be less strict in selecting the rows (the `>` denotes the *immediate* child):

```
$("div.custList table tr")
```

---

That said, you can get the immediate `<td>` children there by [`$(this).children('td')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: didn't know about the insertion of the <tbody> tag. Thanks for the help works great. :)

Comment: In addition, if you would like to get table rows that have at least 1 td, use following code: `$("div.custList table tr:has(td)").click(function () { //Code here });` this will help you skip the first table header row.

Answer (score 22):

Try jQuery's `delegate()` function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.custList table").delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
        alert("You clicked my <tr>!");
        //get <td> element values here!!??
    });
});
```

A delegate works in the same way as `live()` except that `live()` cannot be applied to chained items, whereas `delegate()` allows you to specify an element within an element to act on.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: This answer (with @Bludream update) is the most efficient way to bind events, since you don't have to bind for each tr, just on parent element (which is table in our case).

Answer (score 12):

This work for me!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#tableId tbody tr", function() {
        //some think
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Since TR elements wrap the TD elements, what you're actually clicking is the TD (it then bubbles up to the TR) so you can simplify your selector. Getting the values is easier this way too, the clicked TD is this, the TR that wraps it is this.parent

Change your javascript code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dataGrid td").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked my <td>!" + $(this).html() + 
              "My TR is:" + $(this).parent("tr").html());
        //get <td> element values here!!??
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("body").on("click", "#tableid tr", function () {
    debugger
    alert($(this).text());
});

$("body").on("click", "#tableid td", function () {
    debugger
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).find('td')` will give you an array of td's in the tr.

Comment: Note that this will also return all `<td>` of any **nested** tables. The `children()` returns the *immediate* children, like as `$(this).find('> td')` would do.

Answer (score -3):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("tr").click(function(){
       alert("Click! "+ jQuery(this).find('td').html());
    });
});
</script>
```