# jQuery table row click not working

Tags: jquery

I was checking a few sites, and I came up with the below:

```
    <table class="admin_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Industry</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr url="/home/companies/1">
                <td>Microsoft</td>
                <td>Computer Software</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".admin_table tr").not(':first').click(function() {
        var url = $(this)..attr("url");
        if (url != null && url != '') {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});
```

However, when clicking on the row, it's not responding?

I initially read the following sites for this:

[jQuery - Click event on <tr> elements with in a table and getting <td> element values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458571/jquery-click-event-on-tr-elements-with-in-a-table-and-getting-td-element-val)

[Making a Table Row clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197713/making-a-table-row-clickable)

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/

Is there anything I am missing in my code? In many cases the code is identical...

Comment: There supposed to be `..` (two dots) after `$(this)`?

Comment: If I remove the two dots after `$(this)` it works for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/WbqFj/

Comment: wow...how did I completely miss that. Works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse only the second row should work, since that is the one with the url. But first you should remove the double dots
$(this).attr('url');